# Adicionar url evento json em fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fullcalendar, mongoose

Estou usando o fullcalendar, nodejs e mongoose. 
Já consegui gerar o arquivo json.
Mas ao passar o caminho no js do fullcalendar, nao consigo recuperar os eventos.

Criei um arquivo de teste em json e chamei da seguinte forma:

```
 script(type='text/javascript'). 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.calendar').fullCalendar( {
          header: {
            right: 'prev,next today,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          aspectRatio: 2,
          events: "/calendars.json"
      } );
    });
```

Porem não funciona. 
Queria saber como posso fazer para chamar as informações do mongoose e exibir no calendário.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPt, Nodejs. Você disse que seu código não funciona. Mas, que erro é retornado? [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/68931/edit) sua pergunta e adicione essa e outras informações que achar relevante para resolução do problema. Sugiro uma leitura em [tour] e [ask].

Comment: ja resolvi. Obrigada!

Comment: Como deve ser esse caminho? esse `calendarjson` seria `calendar.json`? usando `events: "/calendars/calendarjson",` como caminho para o arquivo.json

Answer (score 1):

resolvido:
obs: é necessario baixar o js qtip para adicionar pop-up com os eventos.

```
script(type='text/javascript').$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          right: 'prev,next today,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: "/calendars/calendarjson",//caminho arq. json
        eventRender: function(event, element)//abrir popup cm eventos {
          element.qtip({
            content: "" + event.flRoot+""+"<br/>" + "Cliente: " + event.client+""+"<br/>" + "Pauta: " + event.name+"", 
          });
        } 
      });
    });
```